# How to create a MultiQueue that stores Queues?

Tags: generics, collections, queue, java

```
    Queue <E> queue;

    void MultiQueue(){

          this.queue = new LinkedList();
    }

   void MultiQueue(int k){
            //total k numbers of queues must be created.
    }
```

I need to create a multiqueue that can store multiple queues inside. I will create two constructors to build a multiqueue. One of them is to create a multiqueue with just one queue, the other is to create k queues (user dependent.) How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

your member queue should be a Collection of queues:

```
Collection<Queue<E>> queues = new ArrayList<>();

void TestCase()
{
    queues.add( new LinkedList<>()) ;
}

void TestCase(int k)
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < k; i++ )
    {
        queues.add( new LinkedList<>()) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. If it is what you need so please vote up and accept the answer.